# Including BEAM preprocessing graph in Keras models at serving

Tags: tensorflow, keras, apache-beam, google-cloud-ml

Short Question:

Since Tensorflow is moving towards Keras *and* away from Estimators, how can we incorporate our preprocessing pipelines e.g. using `tf.Transform` and `build_serving_input_fn()` (which are used for estimators), into our `tf.keras` models?

---

From my understanding, the only way to incorporate this preprocessing graph is to first build the model using Keras. Train it. Then export it as an estimator using `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator`. Then create a `serving_input_fn` and export the estimator as a saved model, along with this `serving_input_fn` to be used at serving time.

To me it seems tedious, and not the correct way of doing things. Instead, I would like to go directly from Keras to Saved Model.

---

### Problem

I would like to be able to include APAHCE BEAM preprocessing graph in a Keras saved model.

I would like to serve the trained Keras model, hence I export it using SavedModel. Given a trained model, I would like to apply the following logic to predict the outcome.

```
raw_features = { 'feature_col_name': [100] } # features to transform
working_dir = 'gs://path_to_transform_fn' 

# transform features
transformed_features = tf_transform_output.transform_raw_features(raw_features)

model = load_model('model.h5')
model.predict(x=transformed_features)
```

When I define my model, I use Functional API and the model has the following inputs:

```
for i in numerical_features:
    num_inputs.append(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name=i))
```

This is the problem, because tensors are not inputed directly into keras from tf.Dataset, but instead, are linked using the `Input()` layer.

When I export the model using `tf.contrib.saved_model.save_keras_model(model=model, saved_model_path=saved_model_path)`, I can readily serve predictions if I handle the preprocessing in a separate script. The output of this would look like 
[image]

Is this what generally happens? For example, I would preprocess the features as part of some external script, and then send `transformed_features` to the model for prediction.

Ideally, it would all happen within the Keras model/part of a single graph. Currently it seems that I'm using the output of one graph as an input into another graph. Instead I would like to be able to use a single graph.

If using Estimators, we can build a `serving_input_fn()` which can be included as an argument to the estimator, which allows us to incorporate preprocessing logic into the graph.

I would like to also hear your Keras + SavedModel + Preprocessing ideas on serving models using Cloud ML

Comment: Are you using tf2.0?  I haven't used Beam, but to include some simple preprocessing (normalizing and imputing) into a graph for serving I did this:  

1. Use keras Inputs.
2. Use low level tf ops for preprocessing (the perhaps less than ideal part, but not too bad for my use case) `filled_nas_feature = tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(my_feature), tf.zeros_like(my_feature), my_feature)` 


3. Use multiple Keras models to encapsulate preprocessing, training, and postprocessing as callable functions.
4.  Serialize the model to serve using
`tf.saved_model.save(exportModel, './path/to/model')`.

Answer (score 1):

For your question on incorporating Apache Beam into the input function for a tf.transform pipeline, see this TF tutorial that explains how to do that:

"https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/transform/get_started#apache_beam_implementation

On using TF 2.0 SavedModel with Keras, this notebook tutorial demonstrates how to do that:

https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/saving_and_serializing#export_to_savedmodel

Answer (score -2):

The [Cloud ML](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/) is a way of Google Clouds's Machine learning.

It's quite simple to [Get Started](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction) and train the UI using their documentation:

> Develop and validate your training application locally
>
> Before you run your training application in the cloud, get it running
>   locally. Local environments provide an efficient development and
>   validation workflow so that you can iterate quickly. You also won't
>   incur charges for cloud resources when debugging your application
>   locally. Get your training data
>
> The relevant data files, adult.data and adult.test, are hosted in a
>   public Cloud Storage bucket. For purposes of this sample, use the
>   versions on Cloud Storage, which have undergone some trivial cleaning,
>   instead of the original source data. See below for more information
>   about the data.
>
> You can read the data files directly from Cloud Storage or copy them
>   to your local environment. For purposes of this sample you will
>   download the samples for local training, and later upload them to your
>   own Cloud Storage bucket for cloud training.
>   Download the data to a folder:

```
mkdir data
gsutil -m cp gs://cloud-samples-data/ml-engine/census/data/* data/
```

Then, just set the TRAIN_DATA AND EVAL_DATA variables to your local file paths. For example, the following commands set the variables to local paths.

```
TRAIN_DATA=$(pwd)/data/adult.data.csv
EVAL_DATA=$(pwd)/data/adult.test.csv
```

Then you have a TSV file like this:

```
39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
50, Self-emp-not-inc, 83311, Bachelors, 13, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 13, United-States, <=50K
38, Private, 215646, HS-grad, 9, Divorced, Handlers-cleaners, Not-in-family, White, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
53, Private, 234721, 11th, 7, Married-civ-spouse, Handlers-cleaners, Husband, Black, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
```

To run it:

```
gcloud ml-engine local train \
    --module-name trainer.task \
    --package-path trainer/ \
    --job-dir $MODEL_DIR \
    -- \
    --train-files $TRAIN_DATA \
    --eval-files $EVAL_DATA \
    --train-steps 1000 \
    --eval-steps 100
```

For more[Training considerations](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/trainer-considerations) like your question says:

> Running a Training Job
>
> Cloud Machine Learning Engine provides model training as an
>   asynchronous (batch) service. This page describes how to configure and
>   submit a training job by running gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training
>   from the command line or by sending a request to the API at
>   projects.jobs.create. Before you begin
>
> Before you can submit a training job, you must package your
>   application and upload it and any unusual dependencies to a Cloud
>   Storage bucket. Note: If you use the gcloud command-line tool to
>   submit your job, you can package the application and submit the job in
>   the same step. Configuring the job
>
> You pass your parameters to the training service by setting the
>   members of the Job resource, which includes the items in the
>   TrainingInput resource.
>
> If you use the gcloud command-line tool to submit your training jobs,
>   you can:
>
> ```
> Specify the most common training parameters as flags of the gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training command.
> Pass the remaining parameters in a YAML configuration file, named config.yaml by convention. The configuration file mirrors the
> ```
>
> structure of the JSON representation of the Job resource. You pass the
>   path of your configuration file in the --config flag of the gcloud
>   ml-engine jobs submit training command. So, if the path to your
>   configuration file is config.yaml, you must set --config=config.yaml.
>
> Gathering the job configuration data
>
> The following properties are used to define your job.
>
> Job name (jobId)
>       A name to use for the job (mixed-case letters, numbers, and underscores only, starting with a letter). Cluster configuration
>   (scaleTier)
>       A scale tier specifying the type of processing cluster to run your job on. This can be the CUSTOM scale tier, in which case you also
>   explicitly specify the number and type of machines to use. Training
>   application package (packageUris)
>       A packaged training application that is staged in a Cloud Storage location. If you are using the gcloud command-line tool, the
>   application packaging step is largely automated. See the details in
>   the guide to packaging your application. Module name (pythonModule)
>       The name of the main module in your package. The main module is the Python file you call to start the application. If you use the
>   gcloud command to submit your job, specify the main module name in the
>   --module-name flag. See the guide to packaging your application. Region (region)
>       The Compute Engine region where you want your job to run. You should run your training job in the same region as the Cloud Storage
>   bucket that stores your training data. See the available regions for
>   Cloud ML Engine services. Job directory (jobDir)
>       The path to a Cloud Storage location to use for job output. Most training applications save checkpoints during training and save the
>   trained model to a file at the end of the job. You need a Cloud
>   Storage location to save them to. Your Google Cloud Platform project
>   must have write access to this bucket. The training service
>   automatically passes the path you set for the job directory to your
>   training application as a command-line argument named job_dir. You can
>   parse it along with your application's other arguments and use it in
>   your code. The advantage to using the job directory is that the
>   training service validates the directory before starting your
>   application. Runtime version (runtimeVersion)
>
> ```
> The Cloud ML Engine version to use for the job. If you don't specify a runtime version, the training service uses the default Cloud
> ```
>
> ML Engine runtime version 1.0.  Python version (pythonVersion)
>
> ```
> The Python version to use for the job. Python 3.5 is available with Cloud ML Engine runtime version 1.4 or greater. If you don't
> ```
>
> specify a Python version, the training service uses Python 2.7.
>
> Formatting your configuration parameters
>
> How you specify your configuration details depends on how you are
>   starting your training job:
>   Provide the job configuration details to the gcloud ml-engine jobs
>   submit training command. You can do this in two ways:
>
> ```
> With command-line flags.
> In a YAML file representing the Job resource. You can name this file whatever you want. By convention the name is config.yaml.
> ```
>
> Even if you use a YAML file, certain details must be supplied as
>   command-line flags. For example, you must provide the --module-name
>   flag and at least one of --package-path or --packages. If you use
>   --package-path, you must also include --job-dir or --staging-bucket. Additionally, you must either provide the --region flag or set a
>   default region for your gcloud client. These options—and any others
>   you provide as command line flags—will override values for those
>   options in your configuration file.
>
> Example 1: In this example, you choose a preconfigured machine cluster
>   and supply all the required details as command-line flags when
>   submitting the job. No configuration file is necessary. See the guide
>   to submitting the job in the next section.
>
> Example 2: The following example shows the contents of the
>   configuration file for a job with a custom processing cluster. The
>   configuration file includes some but not all of the configuration
>   details, assuming that you supply the other required details as
>   command-line flags when submitting the job.
>
> trainingInput:   scaleTier: CUSTOM   masterType: complex_model_m
>   workerType: complex_model_m   parameterServerType: large_model
>   workerCount: 9   parameterServerCount: 3   runtimeVersion: '1.13'
>   pythonVersion: '3.5'
>
> The above example specifies Python version 3.5, which is available
>   when you use Cloud ML Engine runtime version 1.4 or greater.
>
> **Submitting the job**
>
> When submitting a training job, you specify two sets of flags:
>
> ```
> Job configuration parameters. Cloud ML Engine needs these values to set up resources in the cloud and deploy your application on each
> ```
>
> node in the processing cluster.
>       User arguments, or application parameters. Cloud ML Engine passes the value of these flags through to your application.
>
> Submit a training job using the gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training
>   command.
>
> First, it's useful to define some environment variables containing
>   your configuration details. To create a job name, the following code
>   appends the date and time to the model name:
>
> ```
> TRAINER_PACKAGE_PATH="/path/to/your/application/sources"
> now=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
> JOB_NAME="your_name_$now"
> MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE="trainer.task"
> JOB_DIR="gs://your/chosen/job/output/path"
> PACKAGE_STAGING_PATH="gs://your/chosen/staging/path"
> REGION="us-east1"
> RUNTIME_VERSION="1.13"
> ```
>
> The following job submission corresponds to configuration example 1
>   above, where you choose a preconfigured scale tier (basic) and you
>   decide to supply all the configuration details via command-line flags.
>   There is no need for a config.yaml file:
>
> ```
> gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
>         --scale-tier basic \
>         --package-path $TRAINER_PACKAGE_PATH \
>         --module-name $MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE \
>         --job-dir $JOB_DIR \
>         --region $REGION \
>         -- \
>         --user_first_arg=first_arg_value \
>         --user_second_arg=second_arg_value
> ```
>
> The following job submission corresponds to configuration example 2
>   above, where some of the configuration is in the file and you supply
>   the other details via command-line flags:
>
> ```
> gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
>         --package-path $TRAINER_PACKAGE_PATH \
>         --module-name $MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE \
>         --job-dir $JOB_DIR \
>         --region $REGION \
>         --config config.yaml \
>         -- \
>         --user_first_arg=first_arg_value \
>         --user_second_arg=second_arg_value
> ```
>
> Notes:
>
> ```
> If you specify an option both in your configuration file (config.yaml) and as a command-line flag, the value on the command
> ```
>
> line overrides the value in the configuration file.
>       The empty -- flag marks the end of the gcloud specific flags and the start of the USER_ARGS that you want to pass to your application.
>       Flags specific to Cloud ML Engine, such as --module-name, --runtime-version, and --job-dir, must come before the empty -- flag. The Cloud ML Engine service interprets these flags.
>       The --job-dir flag, if specified, must come before the empty -- flag, because Cloud ML Engine uses the --job-dir to validate the path.
>       Your application must handle the --job-dir flag too, if specified. Even though the flag comes before the empty --, the --job-dir is also
>   passed to your application as a command-line flag.
>       You can define as many USER_ARGS as you need. Cloud ML Engine passes --user_first_arg, --user_second_arg, and so on, through to your
>   application.

Comment: I'm sorry but the question is not on how to use CloudML, but how to incorporate Apache Beam preprocessing graphs into Keras instead of Estimators.